# ArcPy QueryPointAndDistance: Incorrect Lengths?

Tags: arcpy, linear-referencing

Background:

I'm currently trying to determine the chainage (distance m) of my points along a polyline (i.e. proposed railway alignment). A colleague within my firm assisted me with the following script

```
# @date 06/03/2015
# @author Cindy Williams
#
# Returns the distance a point is along a line. Assumes that the
# existing point and line feature classes have the same spatial reference,
# and the points are snapped to the line.
#
# For use as a standalone script.
#

import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Some\Arb\Folder\work.gdb"

# Input variables
fc_line = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer("ftr_line")
fc_pnt = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer("ftr_point")

# Get line geometry - assumes only one feature in feature class
polyline = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_line, "SHAPE@").next()[0]

# Loop over the point feature class
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_pnt, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Get the percentage the current point is along the line
        perc = polyline.queryPointAndDistance(row[0], True)[1]

        # Calculate the percentage distance in metres
        dist = polyline.getLength()*perc
        print("% along line: {0}%\tDistance along line: {1}m".format(round(perc*100, 2), round(dist, 2)))

print("Script complete.")
```

Comparison:

I compared the values generated by the following script and splitting the polyline manually based on the points positions. The values differ appromimately by 4m.

[image]

The following is the first position along the line and the value determined by the script is 871 m and the value determined manually is 875 m.

[image]

Comment: Are the datasets in the same coordinate system?

Comment: @Hornbydd They are indeed, its the first thing a checked when I realised that there was a difference in the lengths. I was try to figure out if it had anything to do with the fact that its based on percentage.

Comment: If a spatial reference isn't specified, you will get geometry errors.  here is one example https://geonet.esri.com/thread/10256 You can specify it within the searchcursor as indicated in the help  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000

Comment: Just replace .getLength() with .length if they are in the same projection. Even simpler: dist=polyline.measureOnLine(row[0]) and remove next line

Comment: @DanPatterson Thanks for the following. I'll test the following and get back to you.

Comment: dist=polyline.measureOnLine(row[0]) did the trick for me.